# Android Application Development AndroidStaggeredGrid Library, can not see the images in StaggeredGrid view format

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, staggered-gridview, etsy

I am developing an android application, where I suppose to show all the gallery images in a fragment. I have got the fragment working with all gallery images in it as thumbnails. Then I wanted to show all images in Mosaic Format but could not find anything regarding that. 
    So I decided to use AndroidStaggeredGrid library to show the images in ETsy style.
    I have successfully imported the library, I have made some changes to code according to AndroidStaggeredGrid's github page. but the images are still appearing in the same format as normal gallery and columns. 
    Can someone please help me with it. below is the code.

Adaptor- This is Adaptor for my imageview. 
Here i have added background color just to test if its working fine. but its not.

```
package com.ultimate.camera.adapters;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.etsy.android.grid.util.DynamicHeightImageView;
import com.ultimate.camera.R;
import com.ultimate.camera.adapters.items.PhotoItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class PhotoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PhotoItem>{
private static final String TAG = "PhotoAdaptor";
    private Context context;
    private int resourceId;
    private final Random mRandom;
    private final ArrayList<Integer> mBackgroundColors;

    private static final SparseArray<Double> sPositionHeightRatios = new SparseArray<Double>();

    public PhotoAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
                                 List<PhotoItem> items, boolean useList) {
        super(context, resourceId, items);
        mRandom = new Random();
        this.context = context;
        this.resourceId = resourceId;
        mBackgroundColors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        mBackgroundColors.add(R.color.orange);
        mBackgroundColors.add(R.color.green);
        mBackgroundColors.add(R.color.blue);
        mBackgroundColors.add(R.color.yellow);
        mBackgroundColors.add(R.color.grey);
    }
 private class ViewHolder {
        DynamicHeightImageView photoImageView;
    }

    /**
     * Populate the view holder with data.
     * @param position
     * @param convertView
     * @param parent
     * @return
     */
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        PhotoItem photoItem = getItem(position);
        View viewToUse = null;

 LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            viewToUse = mInflater.inflate(resourceId, null);
            holder.photoImageView = (DynamicHeightImageView) viewToUse.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            viewToUse.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            viewToUse = convertView;
            holder = (ViewHolder) viewToUse.getTag();
        }

        double positionHeight = getPositionRatio(position);
        int backgroundIndex = position >= mBackgroundColors.size() ?
                position % mBackgroundColors.size() : position;
        Log.d(TAG, "getView position:" + position + " h:" + positionHeight);

        // Set the thumbnail

        holder.photoImageView.setImageURI(photoItem.getThumbnailUri());
        holder.photoImageView.setHeightRatio(positionHeight);

        viewToUse.setBackgroundResource(mBackgroundColors.get(backgroundIndex));

        return viewToUse;
    }

    private double getPositionRatio(final int position) {
        double ratio = sPositionHeightRatios.get(position, 0.0);

if (ratio == 0) {
            ratio = getRandomHeightRatio();
            sPositionHeightRatios.append(position, ratio);
            Log.d(TAG, "getPositionRatio:" + position + " ratio:" + ratio);
        }
        return ratio;
    }

    private double getRandomHeightRatio() {
        return (mRandom.nextDouble() / 2.0) + 1.0; // height will be 1.0 - 1.5 the width
    }
}
```

PhotoItem java This interface is to get the photoItem for adaptor

```
package com.ultimate.camera.adapters.items;

import android.net.Uri;
public class PhotoItem {
private Uri thumbnailUri;
    private Uri fullImageUri;

    public PhotoItem(Uri thumbnailUri,Uri fullImageUri) {
        this.thumbnailUri = thumbnailUri;
        this.fullImageUri = fullImageUri;
    }

    /**
     * Getters and setters
     */
    public Uri getThumbnailUri() {
        return thumbnailUri;
    }

    public void setThumbnailUri(Uri thumbnailUri) {
        this.thumbnailUri = thumbnailUri;
    }

    public Uri getFullImageUri() {
        return fullImageUri;
    }

    public void setFullImageUri(Uri fullImageUri) {
        this.fullImageUri = fullImageUri;
    }
}
```

PhotoGalleryFragment XML Layot for Phot Gallery

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <!--<FrameLayout-->

        <!--android:layout_width="fill_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="fill_parent">-->
        <!--<GridView-->
            <!--style="@style/GridView.PhotoGallery"-->
            <!--android:id="@android:id/list"-->
            <!--android:numColumns="3" />-->

        <com.etsy.android.grid.StaggeredGridView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            app:item_margin="8dp"
            app:column_count="2"


            ></com.etsy.android.grid.StaggeredGridView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>
    <!--</FrameLayout>-->
</LinearLayout>
```

Photo Item XML

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/photo_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/photo_height">


        <com.etsy.android.grid.util.DynamicHeightImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

PhotoGalleryFragment.Java

```
package com.ultimate.camera.fragments;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.etsy.android.grid.StaggeredGridView;
import com.ultimate.camera.R;
import com.ultimate.camera.activities.MainActivity;
import com.ultimate.camera.adapters.PhotoAdapter;
import com.ultimate.camera.adapters.items.PhotoItem;
import com.ultimate.camera.utilities.PhotoGalleryAsyncLoader;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class SimplePhotoGalleryListFragment extends BaseFragment implements AbsListView.OnItemClickListener,
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<PhotoItem>>  {
protected OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
   // protected AbsListView mListView;
    protected PhotoAdapter mAdapter;
    protected ArrayList<PhotoItem> mPhotoListItem;
    protected TextView mEmptyTextView;
    protected ProgressDialog mLoadingProgressDialog;
    protected StaggeredGridView mListView;

    /**
     * Required empty constructor
     */
    public SimplePhotoGalleryListFragment() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Static factory method
     * @param sectionNumber
     * @return
     */
    public static SimplePhotoGalleryListFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        SimplePhotoGalleryListFragment fragment = new SimplePhotoGalleryListFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create an empty loader and pre-initialize the photo list items as an empty list.
        Context context = getActivity().getBaseContext();

        // Set up empty mAdapter
        mPhotoListItem = new ArrayList<PhotoItem>() ;
        mAdapter = new PhotoAdapter(context,
                R.layout.photo_item,
                mPhotoListItem, false);

        // Prepare the loader.  Either re-connect with an existing one,
        // or start a new one.
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = null;
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photo_gallery, container, false);

        // Set the mAdapter
        mListView = (StaggeredGridView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        ((AdapterView<ListAdapter>) mListView).setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mEmptyTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.empty);

        // Show the empty text / message.
        resolveEmptyText();

        // Set OnItemClickListener so we can be notified on item clicks
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }
protected void resolveEmptyText(){
        if(mAdapter.isEmpty()){
            mEmptyTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            setEmptyText();
        } else {
            mEmptyTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
            // Show a progress dialog.
            mLoadingProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            mLoadingProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading Photos...");
            mLoadingProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            mLoadingProgressDialog.show();
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
        cancelProgressDialog();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        cancelProgressDialog();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        cancelProgressDialog();
    }

    /**
     * This is only triggered when the user selects a single photo.
     * @param parent
     * @param view
     * @param position
     * @param id
     */

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (null != mListener) {
            // Tell the share builder to add the photo to the share operation.
            PhotoItem photoListItem = (PhotoItem)this.mAdapter.getItem(position);
            String imagePath = photoListItem.getThumbnailUri().getPath();
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(MainActivity.SELECT_PHOTO_ACTION);
            resetFragmentState();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Used when hitting the back button to reset the mFragment UI state
     */
    protected void resetFragmentState(){
        // Clear view state
        getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        ((BaseAdapter) mListView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
public void setEmptyText() {
        mEmptyTextView.setText("No Photos!");
    }

    /**
     * Loader Handlers for loading the photos in the background.
     */
    @Override
    public Loader<List<PhotoItem>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        // This is called when a new Loader needs to be created.  This
        // sample only has one Loader with no arguments, so it is simple.
        return new PhotoGalleryAsyncLoader(getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<PhotoItem>> loader, List<PhotoItem> data) {
        // Set the new data in the mAdapter.
        mPhotoListItem.clear();

        for(int i = 0; i < data.size();i++){
            PhotoItem item = data.get(i);
            mPhotoListItem.add(item);
        }

        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        resolveEmptyText();
        cancelProgressDialog();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<PhotoItem>> loader) {
        // Clear the data in the mAdapter.
        mPhotoListItem.clear();
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        resolveEmptyText();
        cancelProgressDialog();
    }

    /**
     * Save cancel for the progress loader
     */
    private void cancelProgressDialog(){
        if(mLoadingProgressDialog != null){
            if(mLoadingProgressDialog.isShowing()){
                mLoadingProgressDialog.cancel();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Output
[image: My Output Format]

[image: Expected Format]

You can see in my output images are of the same size thumbnails, I dont have text though. but i expect all images to be of different size thumbnails.

I would really appriciate if someone help me with this. 
Also if anyone know how to create a Mosaic Formation of the images I have given the mosaic formate image as well [image: Mosaic Format]

Comment: okay Try to remove this line    holder.photoImageView.setHeightRatio(positionHeight); from your getView() method of adapter....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After scratching my head again for few more time, Finally I have figured out the answer.
The problem was in PhotoItem Layout file (PhotoItem.XML) where i have defined layout for each photoItem thats gonna show up in fragment. 
There was a FrameLayout as a parent of DynamicImageView section, Which had its own width and height due to which, its not allowing to set a dynamic hight holder.photoImageView.setHeightRation(positionHeight) to a PhotoItem.
So, the only change was PhotoItem.XML, I have to keep rest of the code as it is.

So I had to remove the FrameLayout section and keep only DynamicImageView as a PhotoItem Layout.

PhotoItem.XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.etsy.android.grid.util.DynamicHeightImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then It worked fine and done for now, I have attached the screenshot below  :)

I would still be looking for Mosaic View Solution though

Thanks

[image: Final Output (Expected)]

Answer (score 0):

You got all images of the same size because of holder.photoImageView.setHeightRatio(positionHeight); you sat heightRatio for your images so remove this line and all its effect.. try to remove        holder.photoImageView.setHeightRatio(positionHeight);

Comment: I have tried to remove holder.photoImageView.setHeightRatio(positionHeight); and the other time i have also tried to remove BackgroundColor. But both thime the result stays same. Its not changing anything.

Comment: ok however i am sure that height ration is not important or required for dynamicHeight Imageview . if you apply it then it make same height ration for your dynamic height imageview...

Comment: Yah, I dont know why..but in this case when I tried to remove the heightRatio, It shows the images smaller than the thumbnails. So I had to keep the HeightRatio.

Comment: yes it is because of android:scaleType="centerCrop"  so you can use android:scaleType="fitxy" instead. (dynamicHeight imageview ).